# To pass an event while uninstalling an app

Tags: android

i am developing an app, in which some data is written in a file during a process in the app.
Now what i need to do is to delete that data from that same file during uninstallation and want that same file to be there in the mobile. Can anybody tell me,, is it possible ?

Comment: Can i know the reason for a negative vote?

Comment: I don't know the reason for downvote. But I can tell you that this is not possible using a stock device with public APIs. The system does not give your application any warning that it is about to be uninstalled. Doing so would make it easier for applications to do nefarious things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no way of knowing this (in short of exploiting some security hole in Android). Just like @FoamyGuy said, this could make an app do a bunch of bad things. There is an intent called `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` which is broadcasted when an application is uninstalled. The catch is it is send to all apps **except** the one being uninstalled.

This is confirmed here in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)

Now if you are feeling especially *nefarious* and if you have two of your apps on the users device, then you can listen to the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` intent for each other. But that isnt very feasible and a story for another day.

Comment: super..just super info..

Comment: @Ahmed Aeon Axan ,,, yeah was thinking ,,same like you did, means to have two apps. But now i think it will be just a waste of time